# Any ideas other than using Javascript for this task?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

Hey everyone I just need a quick idea or suggestion on how I could accomplish this task. I have an avatar selection screen where a user can choose one of the avatars for our website. When a user hovers over and clicks on an avatar I have a red 6px border that appears around the selected avatar. Now I want some text to appear over or below the avatar as well. I need to get it out fairly quickly since we are going live soon, so nothing too convoluted. What are some fast simple methods I might be able to use? I'm ok at javascript but I am trying to avoid using it and I can not think of any other way, like maybe z-index or img on an img? Here is what it looks like so far. Again, any suggestions or ideas not using javascript please.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? How are you putting the red border there in the first place?

Comment: Just using a :hover pseudo code. I tried z-index but I don't think thats a good route cant seem to quite get it right.

Comment: *"I need to get it out fairly quickly since we are going live soon, so nothing too convoluted."* Your release schedule isn't our concern. I should think you'd feel fortunate to get *any* answer, even ones that may be "convoluted".

Comment: I guess the real question was is there any other way to do it without javascript. Maybe with some css trickery, I guess not. Oh @cookiemonster I know my schedule is of no ones concern, I was maybe hoping someone knew of a quick css fix or something.

Comment: Quick usually means ugly, which leads to unreadable, which results in headaches when maintaining. But I suppose Dryden Long's answer works, if you really want to use CSS. Even though the javascript versions aren't convoluted either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `+` (adjacent sibling) selector to show a hidden element on hover like so:

HTML

```
<img src="http://www.placekitten.com/200/200" />
<span>Hello World!</span>
```

CSS

```
span{
  display:none;
}
img:hover + span {
  display:block;
}
```

Here is a fiddle of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/uH7g4/

Comment: Thank you, thats what I needed. I didn't want to rely on javascript all the time.

Answer (score 1):

I dunno if we can accomplish this using css, but I can help you out by using Javascript for this task. Firstly, draw these images on a canvas, once that is done, simply use this Javascript code (I am assuming that the variable you have for your canvas is "canvas");

```
    var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
            canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",mouseDownHandler,false);
            function mouseDownHandler(){
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                ctx.font = "30px Arial";
                ctx.fillText("Your Text",xCoordinate,yCoordinate);
            }
```

I have left the xCoord and yCoord, that will be adjusted accordingly, if you want it to be the centre point then do this

```
  var xCoordinate = canvas.style.width/2;
  var yCoordinate = canvas.style.height/2;
```

then simply plug this values in.

Answer (score 0):

For the border, it's okay to use :hover, since you want to change the **appearance** of the avatar on hover. However, also showing a piece of text requires a change in **content**. To do this using CSS is wrong, since CSS is supposed to be for appearance, not context.

Therefore, I would still suggest you do it using javascript. The positioning and appearance of the text can be done using CSS. However, for making the text appear, you should use javascript.